# Can I edit HTML in my Kickstarter campaign?

Tags: html, kickstarter

I'm finding the Kickstarter editor somewhat clumsy and not able to exactly express what I want on my page for whitespace and other details.  Is there a way to edit HTML directly?  For example, when inserting images, I'm getting an extra line break between adjacent images.  I'd like them closer together, but would rather not stitch them together into a single image since I want them to be individually clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of at least the end of 2015, there is no feature available to directly edit HTML for a Kickstarter campaign.